# regex to validate in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm trying to validate an email address with the following rules:
1 to 64 characters (lowercase, uppercase, digits or .) plus @ plus another 1 to 64 characters (lowercase, uppercase, digits or .)

I tried with this

```
function validate(str) {
      const regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9\.]){1,64}$@([a-zA-Z0-9\.]){1,64}$/;
      return regex.test(str);
    }
```

but it's not working. Any idea why?

Comment: Try without that `$` planted in the middle

Comment: check this https://regex101.com/r/lFccVe/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inserted the end of string anchor before the `@` symbol and did not use the start of string anchor `^`. Also, remove the redundant capturing groups.

Use

```
regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,64}@[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,64}$/
         ^                 ^^
```

Comment: To this question wouldn't a link to http://emailregex.com/ be the appropriate answer? ;)

Comment: @D.Kovács: No, because the requirements are different.